# How to resolve ftp url with special characters like @,$?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ipad

Can someone suggest how to resolve the ftp url with special characters.

Answer (score 2):

Take the string, use the `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` method to escape it, then you can use it normally:

```
NSString *fuzzyUrl = @"ftp://jailbreak.apple.com/?foo=@@@&bar=$$$&baz=¥¥¥";
NSString *urlString = [fuzzyUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
// ...
// your code here
// ...
[url release];
```